# Not able to run Flutter doctor on macos

Tags: flutter

I installed flutter 3.0.5 on two macbooks, both macbooks are intel chip.

On one MacBook flutter is running fine.
On the second macbook, I am able to run flutter channel
But when I am running flutter doctor, I am getting this error

```
The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3
```

- Changing the channel to beta or master also didn't help
- chown the .config folder didn't help
- chmod the .config folder didn't help

This error happens by either downloading the SDK and extracting it into the desktop or documents or download folder of my user. And also happens if I just install the flutter SDK using brew

Comment: which directory did you extract the sdk to

Comment: This error happens by either downloading the sdk and extract it in the desktop or documents or dowload folder of my user. And also happens if I just install the flutter sdk using brew

Comment: Did you set the flutter SDK path globally?

Comment: Yes brew did that for us

Answer (score 2):

You can do following thing.
As per your query seems to be permission issue where the flutter sdk located.

```
sudo chown -R <your_username> /flutter_sdk_path/
```

Don't forget to replace your username[the name by which you are logged in in Mackbook] and flutter the SDK path.
Once its done then close terminal and open again and  run flutter doctor command.
Note : updating permission may need restart of system soemtimes.

Comment: Hi thanks but we did that too and that didn't help too

Comment: You can do one thing re download sdk and remove old one totaly and try for the same

Answer (score 0):

**Please Check The Below Permission**

- The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
- Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has
  read/write permissions for the current user.
- Read the documentation for proper installation then try again-
  https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos

Comment: Yes this what we did but still we got the same error only on this one macbook

Answer (score 0):

Redownload the flutter and put it inside your user's directory or just cut that flutter SDK and paste it inside the **Users/{yourUserName}/Desktop** or **Documents** folder and map that path to the env variable and also in android studio. Make sure that android studio has enough permissions inside the MAC.

Answer (score 0):

First run flutter cmd like ( use your flutter file path)

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/Users/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

after run this cmd

```
Flutter doctor
```